# infinite horizontal image gallery in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, infinite

Im trying to do infinite horizontal image gallery but cannot figure out few problems.I got a div that has 100% width and inside second div that has very big width so the images can be next to each other.Im in testing phase so function is running immediately after page loads so the gallery is moved left by margin of width first image and then it has to be appended as last child and its looks like thats working but right after first append its happening on and on with another images.How can i avoid it?And my second question is when i want to do the moving on hover for example on some arrow as long as im over that how can i cycle this function correctly?Thanks very much.

Here is the [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aubp2ga7/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="slide-container">
        <div class="slide" id="slide"><img src="clique.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="rollyx.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="grafrollyx.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="grafagent.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="grafrollyx.jpg"></div>                            
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function slider(){
    var what = $('#slide').width();


    $('.slide').first().animate({marginLeft: -(what)}, 0, setTimeout(function() {
        $('.slide')
            .first()
            .appendTo($('.slide').parent())
            .css({ marginLeft: 0 });
    }, 1000))
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Superman/mANPs/) is helpful.

Comment: in this case is few things that i can use so thanks but thats something other that i need these pictures are fixed in html as they going so when it reach last picture you need to go back and i want to infinite strip so element that is outside of visible area becomes the last one but anyway thanks..

Answer (score 1):

i guss this is a better way of doing that

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8a7Mm/8/) of the gallery.

1. Put all your images in a hidden div
2. Clone them and put them in the visible div
3. Animate the image by changing the left margin
4. You can adjust the time between images by the set interval function
5. You can adjust the slidein time by the animate time.

JS

```
var pictxtnumber = 1;
loadpictxt(pictxtnumber);

var fadeintime = 500;
animatediv();

function animatediv()
{
    var number = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() { 
                                           pictxtnumber = pictxtnumber + 1;
                                           if(pictxtnumber > 6)
                                             {
                                              pictxtnumber = 1;
                                              }
                                           loadpictxt(pictxtnumber);

                                           }, 1000);
}

function loadpictxt(num)
{
  $('.picturediv').html('');
  $(".hiddenimage img:nth-child(" + num + ") ").clone().appendTo('.picturediv');
  $('.picturediv img').css('margin-left', '100px');
  $('.picturediv img').animate({marginLeft: "0"}, 100);    
}
```

Comment: tanks for the effort but i dont think this is good way for that im trying to make because it is pointless to have pictures that has to be visible on the beginning inside hide div it takes a while before they appears and i dont think moving elements from div to another div is solution, when suffice to move first (or last ) picture move outside visible area and then append it to end thats practically same as appending from another element and my point is to have visible these outer pictures that are fading out visible till they arent outside of screen